# Best Practice for SOLR with long text data query

Tags: solr

im getting some hiccups on SOLR while importing address data and indexing.
would like to have some advise on this and what would be the best practice to do so.

currently what im trying to do is to load in the full string address into SOLR and then perform search by keyword on a address string.

for example data i have imported:
address: "12 Hagley Road Five Ways, Birmingham B16 8SJ, United Kingdom"

search keyword: "Hagley Road Five Ways"
would actually return me the result.

the query works fines. but im facing issue during data import and reindexing. its taking too long and slow and getting time out error.data volume about 10mil records.

also i do have a copyfield of the address field with docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="true"

Comment: How are you indexing your content now? How often does it change? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: sorry, the volume is about 40mil, but we have not manage to complete the load. so you may assume it does not change often. reindexing we are using talend.
 for the error wise, we do see in the solr side "Unable to create core [smart_search_v3_shard1_replica_n2] Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
 at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1084)

Comment: on talend etl side we do see error 
talend side 
 Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got application/json. {
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.net.SocketTimeoutException"],
    "msg":"Error trying to proxy request for url: http

Comment: Drop using DIH for very large imports - you'll see far better results by creating a custom indexing solution (which can be a simple application in Java/python/etc.) that connects to your database and extracts the relevant rows before submitting them to Solr. It'll allow you to multithread processing and submit documents far quicker, in addition to making changes to the data submitted easier. Use `commitWithin` if you want data to become visible while submitting, otherwise issue a commit manually after all the data has been submitted from all threads.